# What is wrong with this imfinfo command

Tags: image, octave

I'm trying to manipulate an image with both `read` and `imfinfo` commands.  Octave gives a syntax error for this command.

```
imfinfo(C:Users\konra\Documents\work_stuff\Lochow\210329_Pacitti\210810_photos\DJI_0002.jpg)
                                                               ^
```

The little carrot is under the "i" in 210329_Pacitti

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, you forgot to include the actual error!

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the path between apostrophe like this

```
imfinfo('C:Users\konra\Documents\work_stuff\Lochow\210329_Pacitti\210810_photos\DJI_0002.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks.  After posting this message I was able to find the answer.  It was about what you said.  I'm very new to Octave also.  My original computer programming used punch cards